# Error building Visual Studio 2010 Silverlight 4 projects on Windows 7 with XP Mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I installed Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 in an XP Mode VM on Windows 7. Then I created a trivial Silverlight 4 (beta) project and tried to build it. I get the following error:

> Error 1   The "ValidateXaml" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'file://\tsclient\d\Users\me\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\SilverlightApplication2\SilverlightApplication2\obj\Debug\SilverlightApplication2.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation
>   is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515)
>
> File name:
>   'file://\tsclient\d\Users\me\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\SilverlightApplication2\SilverlightApplication2\obj\Debug\SilverlightApplication2.dll'
>   --->  System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly
>   from a network location which would
>   have caused the assembly to be
>   sandboxed in previous versions of the
>   .NET Framework. This release of the
>   .NET Framework does not enable CAS
>   policy by default, so this load may be
>   dangerous. If this load is not
>   intended to sandbox the assembly,
>   please enable the
>   loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569
>   for more information.
>
> at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection,
>   Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue,
>   AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String
>   assemblyFile)    at
>   Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.ValidateXaml.XamlValidator.Execute(ITask
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.ValidateXaml.XamlValidator.Execute(ITask
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.ValidateXaml.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost
>   taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext
>   taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost,
>   ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode
>   howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)

I believe this is related to the fact that XP Mode redirects the My Documents folder to the host, turning it into a network share location, and some sort of CAS / security policy is being triggered.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Have you added `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>` in your configuration file?

Comment: Kevin, did you see my comment? -> devenv.exe.config

Answer (score 4):

Enabling loadFromRemoteSources is also explained on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/webdevelopmentprerelease/thread/ea9b9cab-cbfd-496d-8a81-7b3dd06e8c23 along with another option; set the environment variable COMPLUS_EnableLegacyCASPolicy.

**Edit:** (copy and paste from the above URL as the post got taken down)

David DeWinter - MSFT (Wednesday, May 20, 2009 2:10 AM)

Caveat: I'm not on the security team but will attempt to answer this nonetheless...

What's happening here is that the build tasks for Silverlight are attempting to load an assembly that, in previous versions of the CLR, would classify it as a partial trust assembly based on its evidence (e.g. its zone) according to CAS policy.

In CLR 4.0, CAS policy is totally deprecated and is not even enabled by default. Under the circumstances, though, it appears the CLR throws an Exception when what would be a partial trust load in CLR 2.0 is a full trust load in CLR 4.0.

The loadFromRemoteSources switch the Exception message refers to is in the runtime element under configuration and looks like this:

```
<runtime>
  <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true|false" />
</runtime>
```

This will not enable legacy CAS policy but will allow you (or, in this case, the build system) to load remote assemblies with the same permissions as the host AppDomain. In this case it seems as though you could modify the configuration for the build system (which I assume in this case would be Visual Studio: %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config) to enable this switch.

If you don't want to modify that configuration then you can set the environment variable COMPLUS_EnableLegacyCASPolicy to 1, which will enable CAS Policy that was present in CLR 2.0 and also allow Silverlight to load this task.

Hope that helps.
David, Blog - http://blogs.rev-net.com/ddewinter/ Twitter - @ddewinter

Comment: Putting the URL above into [link]http://www.archive.org/ seems to work for now.

To do the loadFromRemoteSources close VS 2010, then open the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config file and adding the loadFromRemoteSources element as follows: <runtime> <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" /> </runtime>

Answer (score 3):

It should work if you add `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>` to **devenv.exe.config**.
More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I truly loathe Microsoft for making it necessary to patch configuration files of third-party applications just so that we can pretend that network shares are just like local drives.

Comment: Do not have such file here :(