# Cant trust a project .DLL on a network location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am having an issue of editing a Visual Studio project by which it is saved on a remote server at home.

First of all, my setup is:-

1. Windows 8 64bit RC, With Visual Studio 2010 installed.
2. Windows Server 2012 RC. With a Shared Folder accessed with an account (//Dev).

The problem here is from Windows 8 RC, I can access the share and create the projects I want. But if I build the project I got this error:-

Could not load the assembly file:///C:\***.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web. If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more information.

I tried to unblock the .DLL file from its properties but the UNBLOCK button is not available.

Plz help.

Comment: Have you tried mapping a drive to your network location?  This may make it appear "local" enough to the OS to unblock.

Comment: I did that from the start, it didn't work.

Comment: Do you get this error with Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread regarding a similar issue:

[Error building Visual Studio 2010 Silverlight 4 projects on Windows 7 with XP Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823339/error-building-visual-studio-2010-silverlight-4-projects-on-windows-7-with-xp-mo)

Adding the <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/> under <configuration> <runtime> in devenv.exe.config actually fixed "This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web" issue for me in VS2010, give it a try.